# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my db

> ```
> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `project` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
> USE `project`;
> ```

checks Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `issue` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `content` (`content`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Issue table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `issues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createtime` date NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `text` (`text`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

The code i try to insert

```
ALTER TABLE  `checks` ADD CONSTRAINT  `context` FOREIGN KEY (  `content` ) REFERENCES  `project`.`issues` (

`text`
) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Error message:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`#sql-1d5c_130`, CONSTRAINT `context` FOREIGN KEY (`content`) REFERENCES `issues` (`text`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Anyone can help ??? I've seen the other posts on this topic, but no luck. Am I overseeing something or any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create an index on **`issues`.`text`** column.

Make sure there is no data in both tables. If there is some data, then make sure for every entry in **`checks`.`content`** the same entry exists in **`issues`.`text`**.